# Mongoose find nested records in specific record

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have my mongoose model/schema set up like this:

```
var servers = mongoose.model('Servers', new mongoose.Schema({
    server_id : String,
    timestamps: []
}));
```

Where I keep a record of servers, storing their server id, and an array containing unix time stamps, which is populated/updated when they receive a request.

I would like to query the timestamps array, to find results between two time stamps, for a specific server_id, e.g. in pseudocode I am trying to do something like this;

```
'find servers.timestamps between timeFrom and timeTo where server_id = serverId'
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to use the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator if your MongoDB server is `3.2.X` or greater. 
The following example filters the `timestamps` array to only include timestamps that fall within a given range i.e. `timeFrom <= t <= timeTo`:

```
servers.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "server_id": serverId,
            "timestamps": {
                "$gte": timeFrom,
                "$lte": timeTo
            }
        } 
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "server_id": 1,
            "timestamps": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$timestamps",
                    "as": "t",
                    "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$gte": [ "$$t", timeFrom ]  },
                            { "$lte": [ "$$t", timeTo ]  }
                        ]                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

---

The other way (if your drivers do not support MongoDB versions `3.2.X` or greater, i.e. supports `>=2.6.X` and `<=3.0.X`) would be to use a combination of the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** and **[`$setDiference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operators to project a filtered array where you filter out (using **[`$setDiference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)**) the false values (derived from the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator), like in the following example:

```
servers.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": { 
            "server_id": serverId,
            "timestamps": {
                "$gte": timeFrom,
                "$lte": timeTo
            }
        } 
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "server_id": 1,
            "timestamps": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$timestamps",
                            "as": "t",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    { 
                                        "$and": [
                                            { "$gte": [ "$$t", timeFrom ]  },
                                            { "$lte": [ "$$t", timeTo ]  }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "$$t",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]).exec(function (err, result){
    console.log(result);
});
```